# Has this patent been granted or only filed?

Tags: intellectual-property, patents

I'm interested in implementing this technique in my app:

https://encrypted.google.com/patents/CA2839098C?cl=en&hl=en

But from this page I can't figure out it the patent has only been filed, or actually granted too.

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Patents listing you provided, the publication type says "Grant", so this appears to be a granted patent.